# ¿Como poner en modo redimensionar a un PictureBox creado dinamicamente en C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, picturebox

Buenas.

Estoy creando una aplicación en C# bajo VisualStudio 2013.

En ella cuando el usuario pulsa en una opción del menu contextual del botón derecho del raton sobre un Panel agrego un PictureBox al Panel.

Hasta aquí todo perfecto pero el problema viene cuando intendo darle la funcionalidad para poder redimensionar el PictureBox pues no consigo que se ponga en modo redimensionable (cuando aparece con puntos en las esquinas y en la mitad de las lados) cuando hago click en el. He revisado todas las propiedades del objeto PictureBox pero no he dado con ninguna que me permita hacer lo que intento.

**Código donde creo el PictureBox y lo añado al Panel**

```
PictureBox cuadroImagenPictureBox = new PictureBox();

cuadroImagenPictureBox.SetBounds(cuadroImagen.PosX, cuadroImagen.PosY, cuadroImagen.Ancho, cuadroImagen.Alto);
cuadroImagenPictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
cuadroImagenPictureBox.Tag = cuadroImagen;
cuadroImagenPictureBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pulsarEnPictureBox);
cuadroImagenPictureBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MoverEnPictureBox);

this.panelHojaActual.Controls.Add(cuadroImagenPictureBox);
```

**Código donde recojo el evento del click**

```
private void pulsarEnPictureBox(object sender,  MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            PictureBox cuadro = (PictureBox)sender;
           // -> Aqui es donde intento cambiar el PictureBox
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabe donde esta mi error u orientarme por donde debo tirar?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Estas buscando redimensionar un control en tiempo de ejecucion? es eso?

Comment: No existe ninguna propiedad o método para hacer lo que buscas. Debes implementarlo manualmente...

Comment: @gbianchi si, ese es mi cometido final.

Comment: @Pikoh eso es lo que intento pero no he conseguido decirle al PictureBox que voy a redimensionarlo. He buscado por todos los sitios pero solo encuentro respuestas para redimensionar la foto interna.

Comment: es que tenes que hacerlo manual. no se va a redimensionar como lo haces en tiempo de diseño. es un trabajo pesado...

Comment: @gbianchi si se que es de forma manual, lo que necesito es que el componente se pinte con la forma de seleccionado y luego ya trabajo yo su redimension en codigo.

Comment: no. eso no va a pasar.. vas a tener que dibujar los bordes a mano e ir trabajandolo.. creo que tenia un ejemplo por algun lado..nunca redimensione.. si movi...

Comment: @gbianchi lo he enfocado de otra manera y en vez de indicar que el componente esta seleccionado para redimensionar lo que he hecho es usar el cursor con forma flechas de redimensionado. La parte de la implementacion he encontrado [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6eb864ff-0ea8-4641-bc2a-83db94371429/resize-a-picturebox-with-mouse?forum=winforms) ¿debería cerrar la pregunta ya que he ido por otro camino?

Comment: no, por favor respondela tu mismo, con la solucion lo mas completa posible que puedas.

Comment: @gbianchi ya esta contestada ¿vale así o tengo que hacer algo mas?

Comment: @MrCode excelente.. en un rato podras aceptarla.. y bienvenido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras mucho pensar decidí cambiar el enfoque y en vez de marcar el componente con los cuadros de seleccionado (esquinas y laterales) use el cursor con forma de flechas de redimensionado para indicar que se esta redimensionado.

Ademas conseguí implementar el redimensionamiento de la siguiente forma:

**NOTA**: En mi caso el botón del ratón que hace el redimensionamiento es el central. Para otros botones cambiar *MouseButtons.Middle* por su valor correspondiente

**Variables dentro de la clase que hereda de Form**

```
public partial class Principal : Form
{
   private Boolean redimensionandoCuadroImagen = false;
   private int marginRedimension = 10;
   private Size tamanoInicioCuadroImagen;
   private Rectangle rectaPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen = Rectangle.Empty;
   private Point puntoInicioArrastreRedimensionCuadroImagen;
   private Control objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen = null;

   ...... // Resto de variables
```

**Metodo que recibe el evento del click en el componente (PictureBox)**

```
private void pulsarEnPictureBox(object sender,  MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        locationCuadroImagen = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen = (Control)sender;

            // Si el click se ha hecho dentro de los margenes cercanos al perimetro del control
            if ((e.X <= marginRedimension) || (e.X >= objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen.Width - marginRedimension) ||
                (e.Y <= marginRedimension) || (e.Y >= objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen.Height - marginRedimension))
            {
                // Activamos la redimension y cambiamos el cursor
                redimensionandoCuadroImagen = true;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;

                // Tamaño inicial
                this.tamanoInicioCuadroImagen = new Size(e.X, e.Y);
                // Obtenemos la localizacion del control
                Point pt = this.PointToScreen(objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen.Location);
                // Creamos el rectangulo pestunteado y lo pintamos
                rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen = new Rectangle(pt, tamanoInicioCuadroImagen);
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
            }
            else
            {
                redimensionandoCuadroImagen = false;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }

            // Obtenemos el punto de inicio del arrastre
            this.puntoInicioArrastreRedimensionCuadroImagen = e.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

**Método que recibe el evento del arrastre con raton en el componente (PictureBox)**

```
private void moverEnPictureBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (locationCuadroImagen != Point.Empty)
        {
            PictureBox cuadro = (PictureBox)sender;

            Point newlocation = cuadro.Location;
            newlocation.X += e.X - locationCuadroImagen.X;
            newlocation.Y += e.Y - locationCuadroImagen.Y;
            cuadro.Location = newlocation;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            if (objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen != null)
            {
                if (redimensionandoCuadroImagen)
                {
                    // Movemos el rectangulo pespunteado
                    if (rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width > 0 && rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height > 0)
                        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
                    rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width = e.X - this.puntoInicioArrastreRedimensionCuadroImagen.X + this.tamanoInicioCuadroImagen.Width;
                    rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height = e.Y - this.puntoInicioArrastreRedimensionCuadroImagen.Y + this.tamanoInicioCuadroImagen.Height;
                    if (rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width > 0 && rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height > 0)
                        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Método que recibe el evento de levantar el boton del raton sobre el componente (PictureBox)**

```
private void soltarEnPictureBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        if (redimensionandoCuadroImagen)
        {
            if (rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width > 0 && rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height > 0)
            {
                // Borramos el rectangulo pespunteado
                ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen, this.ForeColor, FrameStyle.Dashed);
            }
            // Comparamos si hemos redimensionado por debajo de los minimos en cuyo caso redimensionaremos al los minimos
            if (rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width > 100 && rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height > 100)
            {
                // Tamaño seleccionado
                this.objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen.Size = rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Size;
            }
            else
            {
                // Tamaño minimo
                this.objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen.Size = new Size((int)Math.Max(100, rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Width), Math.Max(100, rectanguloPunteadaApoyoRedimensionCuadroImagen.Height));
            }                
        }

        // Ponemos las variables a su valor por defecto
        this.objetoArrastradoCuadroImagen = null;
        this.puntoInicioArrastreRedimensionCuadroImagen = Point.Empty;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```